# Line numbers of less in css

Tags: css, gruntjs, less

I probably have a very simple and stupid question, but I just can't figure it out. 
I know this is possible with grunt and less, but how-where-and-when...

I want my less line-numbers in my rendered css as comments so I can debug faster and easyer. (I know you can add less to your html for developing reasons but its just cleaner to directly write it in css.)

The following outcome is were I'm searching for:

[image: line-numbers less]

Could someone send me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure sourceMaps for LESS using Grunt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743160/how-to-configure-sourcemaps-for-less-using-grunt)

Comment: Can you share what your grunt setup is and what LESS plugin you're using?